# how to make a string for web param?

Tags: php, json, web

hello please I have a link that I have to fill with a parameter that I get with `$_GET`. this link is for a json data.

this is what I have in my json.php :

```
if ($_GET["1"]=="on"){
    $gas.="1";
}    
elseif ($_GET["2"]=="on") {
    $gas.="2";
}
elseif ($_GET["3"]=="on") {
    $gas.="3";    
}
elseif ($_GET["4"]=="on") {
    $gas.="4";    
}
elseif ($_GET["5"]=="on") {
    $gas.="5";    
}
elseif ($_GET["6"]=="on") {
    $gas.="6";    
}
```

the 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6  refers to input type checkbox in my main, the link that I have to build looks like this :

```
http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/project/main.php?community=....&gas=(2,5)&radius=1
```

the question is how to build the (2,5) with  the code given in the beginning

Comment: what does 2,5 even mean? your code is else/elseif statements meaning only one will be truthy. You're better off calling your checkbox `name="gas[]" value="1"` and then you can just get all of the `$_GET['gas']` data as an array if you want to capture multiple checkbox states.

Comment: It means you want to use (2,5) in the url am i right??

Comment: In the url you can not show,  this (2,5) will change in the url as (2%2C5)

Comment: @scuzzy i'm having this link when i did what you say:
http://........................../~moe/project/main.php?community=bei&gas%5B%5D=1&gas%5B%5D=2&gas%5B%5D=3&gas%5B%5D=4&gas%5B%5D=5&gas%5B%5D=6&rayon=1

Comment: Hmm, You're either going to need to use a POST request or have some client side JavaScript to clean up your request variable if you want to keep using GET